# android gridview+baseadapter+scroll issues setting image in background?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using gridview to display 7colums and 96rows. When i click on particular cell it should be highlighted with different image. The cell is highlighted with diff image but when i scroll gridview multiple cells are highlighted with that image instead of single selected cell.
Here is the piece of code for my adapter class.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView txtgridcell = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.gridview_row, null);
        }
        txtgridcell = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtgridcell);
        **if ((rangeList != null && rangeList.size() > 0)
                && (rangeList.contains(position))) {
            txtgridcell
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_background_focused);
        }**
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but you haven't posted the complete code - `getView(...)` should be returning a `View` which your code hasn't included.

Comment: any one having this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2):

solved

```
if ((rangeList != null && rangeList.size() > 0)
                && (rangeList.contains(position))) {
            txtgridcell
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_background_focused);
        } else {
            txtgridcell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_background);
        }
```

Adding else condition resolved my problem.